# Edit Text box value not working using FormArray in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

*I have created dummy json array as given below*

[ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024" } ]

and i tried to click on button using onMy function available in **app.component.ts**. but the same json array i am getting when i am checking in console. please check i have attached screen-shot.

Below is my CODE URL
[CODE URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are console loggin `users`, whereas you want to actually console log the **form** values:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onMy(myForm.value)">
```

TS:

```
onMy(form){
  console.log(form);
}
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-c2oe4r?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Great, glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(this.myForm.controls.users.controls[0].controls.firstname.value);
console.log(this.myForm.controls.users.controls[0].controls.lastname.value);
```

Using formcontrol, get the needed latest response!!!